# How to get String[] String's to a seperate String?

Tags: java, android

I have a list of URL's added to a String[] with this.

```
try {
    Elements thumbs = jsDoc.select("div.latest-media-images img.latestMediaThumb");
    List<String> thumbLinks = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    for(Element thumb : thumbs) {
        thumbLinks.add(thumb.attr("src"));
    }
    for(String thumb : thumbLinks) {
        System.out.println(thumbLinks.get(1));
    }
}
```

How can i add each String that is loaded into a separate String?

EDIT:

SO as the images are loaded into the thumbLinks list. I want to get each link to a seperate

```
String url1;
String url2;
String url3;
```

Comment: Separate `String`s called what?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect a fixed number of items, and you have a fixed number of `String` variables, you have little choice but something like:

```
String url0 = thumbLinks.get(0);
String url1 = thumbLinks.get(1);
...
String url5 = thumbLinks.get(5);
```

Well, you could do something grim with [reflection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html), I guess.  But probably best to avoid this at all.

Comment: So you think this is  a bad idea?

Comment: @coder: Yes, probably.  Why would you want to do this, when it would be simpler to use arrays or containers?

Comment: This is the syntac error i get when i use thumbLinks[0]  The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to List<String>

Comment: @coder: What version of Java are you using?  You may need to use `String url0 = thumbLinks.get(0);`.

Comment: I don't think this is possible even *with* reflection.

Comment: @Null: It's possible if the receiving variables are member variables of a class.

Comment: @Oli How can I do that? I can't find anything that adds fields to a class.

Comment: ohhhh! Got it..Whats dangerous about the way i am doing it now?

Comment: @coder: There's nothing dangerous.  There just doesn't seem to be a good reason to have a bunch of separate variables, rather than an array.  An array or container is much more convenient (you can't iterate over a bunch of variables, for instance).

Comment: Oh check out the answer below at the bottom. Seems to be a good idea also.

Comment: @coder: Both of the other answers are just transferring the contents of your `List` into an array.

Comment: When i use your code inside my last for() it returns the urls like 3 seperate times?

Comment: @coder: I don't understand what you mean.  If you put my code inside your loop, then of course it will be executed multiple times.

Comment: It shouldnt matter though or be to much of a waste

Answer (score 0):

take a String array of the size of your ArrayList object - thumbLinks in your case. take an `int` variable and initialize it with zero. I have made some changes in your code just have a look:

`try{`

```
        Elements thumbs = jsDoc.select("div.latest-media-images img.latestMediaThumb");
        List<String> thumbLinks = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(Element thumb : thumbs) {
            thumbLinks.add(thumb.attr("src"));
        }

        String[] urls = new String[thumbLinks.size()];
        int x =0;
        for(String thumb : thumbLinks) {
            urls[x++] = thumb;
        }
    }catch(Excpetion e){

    }
```

use `urls` for your purpose

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList` has [method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) `public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a)` that you can call as described below on `thumbLinks`:

```
String[] url = new String[thumbLinks.size()];
url = thumbLinks.toArray(url);
```

Then, you will have an array of strings that you can access like this:

```
System.out.println(url[0]);
System.out.println(url[1]);
System.out.println(url[2]);
// etc, etc. all the say up to thumbLinks.size() - 1
```

While this is not *exactly* what you've asked for, it's pretty much the same thing. If you really want variables named `url1, url2, url3, etc.`, you're likely going to have to code it line by line for every element in the list.

Just as an aside, you don't need an array to access the elements of your `thumbLinks` list directly. You can already do this:

```
System.out.println(thumbLinks.get(0));
System.out.println(thumbLinks.get(1));
System.out.println(thumbLinks.get(2));
// etc. all the way up to thumbLinks.size() - 1
```

Comment: IS there a way to add a String for each element it finds?

Comment: Referencing the above code, every element in the `url` array is a variable of type `String` and the `toArray` method will create an element for every element in the `thumbLinks` list. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @coder_For_Life22 with all this being said, I'm not sure there is much of a reason to create an array. You already have the `thumbLinks` list where you can reference any element with `thumbLinks.get(x)` where `x` is any integer from 0 to `thumbLinks.size() - 1`